# copying an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying array by value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

How to copy an array of objects to another array in Javascript?

```
var qwerty1 = arr;
var qwerty2 = arr;
```

Both qwerty1 and qwerty2 may look different but point to the same reference.
I read somewhere that "assigning a boolean or string to a variable makes a copy of that value, while assigning an array or an object to a variable makes a reference to the value." So my two arrays post different operations return the same objects.

Any light in this regard?

Comment: my array arr contains {objects}..So not a copy of the above link @RC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to copy an array in Javascript is to use `concat`:

```
var qwerty1 = arr.concat();
var qwerty2 = arr.concat();
```